# How to define complex scenes in `xeogl`?

Tags: 3d

At https://xeogl.org/docs/classes/SceneJSModel.html there is an example for loading a scene into `xeogl`. Unfortunately there's no definition how to define such a scene. I guess the reason for this is that people that use this kind of stuff typically know about this and it will likely be self explanatory then. Unfortunately I don't know about this stuff and therefor I'd be very happy about some help here.

My goal is to define scenes built from 3D-blocks of different sizes. I'd need some texture with these blocks that scale appropriately with the shape of these boxes. My Idea would be that I could somehow generate such a scene model including information about textures and then render the scene with `xeogl` (including textures).

Q: Is that the correct approach? And if it is the correct approach: Where can I find more information about the definition format? If not: What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

A scene is basically a design space where all the magic happens. But scenes have to be assigned to some standard HTML canvases, so I am not sure whether it is possible to have such complex scenes. This could probably help: https://github.com/xeolabs/xeogl/wiki/Getting-Started.